# How to use pocket hole screws for material thickness of more than 1.5 inches?

Tags: woodworking, joinery

Here is the screw selection table for the Kreg Jig (R).

[image]

This table stops at material thickness of 1.5" and gives screw length of 2.5". I am sure that Kreg is aware that material thickness can be more than this like in a 4x4. How in the world is a person supposed to drill pocket holes into thicker materials and what size screws should be used?

Comment: You're not supposed to. You're misapplying something which works well-enough for what it was made to do to something it wasn't made to do, and won't do well.

Comment: So what is the solution then?

Comment: Depends on the application. Half-lap, mortise and tenon, bridle...

Comment: This can't be answered without supplying at least some detail about what it is you're trying to build or what it is you're trying to fasten together. Once we know that a solution can be suggested.

Comment: I intend to create a frame using wood. This frame will be rectangle, long side vertical. There will be 1 vertical wood in the middle for extra support. I shall mount "tool wall" on this. This is a recangle metal/plastic plate with holes. We put hooks into holes and then mount tools on them. I cannot mount the tool wall directly on the wooden shed wall. Therefore, I shall make a wooden frame and then mount the tool wall on it and then put it on the end of my shed. Does this make sense?

Comment: What are the general dimensions? What kind of wood are you thinking about using?

Comment: wood will be 2x2 or 4x4

Comment: What are you going to _do_ with it? Why would you need 4x4s? Nobody can answer your question if you won't tell us what you have in mind.

Comment: I don't know for sure if I need 2x2 or 4x4. I believe that 2x2 should be sufficiently thick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what it is that you're trying to connect together. We'd need to know more about what you're building to answer fully.

Here are a couple things to keep in mind:

1. The "material thickness" alluded to in the chart above is primarily concerned with the thickness of the piece you're attaching *to* something else, not the piece it's being attached to. Attaching a 3/4" board to a 4x4 wouldn't require screws any longer
   than attaching two 3/4" boards together, but in a situation where
   you're building with 4x4s, you may need a method that's more robust
   than pocket screws.
2. Kreg didn't "invent" pocket screws and if they
   don't make screws long enough for what you're trying to do, there's
   no reason why you can't just use "regular" screws to make the
   connection. Pocket hole screws have been around for hundreds (thousands?) of years. You just need to install the screws at about a 15-degree angle (give or take) to have the screws emerge from roughly the center of the board that you're trying to attach and continue into the board that you're attaching to with enough length to make a strong connection.

Pocket hole screws are a viable method of connecting boards together but they are wildly over-used or over-implemented these days in situations where there are much stronger (and arguably easier to do) alternatives. Pocket holes tend to "lose their grip" in situations where stress is placed on the joints--like movement, seasonal expansion/contraction, etc.  The screws can pull out, the thin pieces of wood that the screws are in also is prone to splintering or breaking, and there isn't much side-to-side strength either.

Comment: I will make a frame using wood. Then, I will mount a "tool wall" on this frame.

Comment: Sounds good... What kind of wood? What are the dimensions of the "tool wall" and what are the dimensions of the frame and the wood planks you want to use? What are you doing with 4x4s? Can you post a photo or sketch of what you want to build? What tools and experience to you have available?

Comment: And again, this sounds like something where you will get more and better advice in the woodworking stack than here in the home-improvement stack.

Comment: @keshlam Can't be answered on WW without more details either.

Comment: @gnicko: True, but that's still the right community to ask, I think. Unless we're talking about using pocket screws specifically for home improvement.

Comment: @keshlam I don't see much else happening with it in either place without more info. As written, the question is: _What to do when we go off the Kreg application chart?_ which is, I think, a pretty good fit in either place. I think we've more than answered that question here. Once the OP figures out what it is he's trying to build and/or how he's thinking to do it, a separate, follow-up question regarding whether or not pocket screws are his best choice would be perfect for WW.

Comment: Granted., @gnicko.

Answer (score 4):

IF you can get long enough screws with suitable heads, which Kreg may not offer, the table should extend along straight lines.

Note that all of this is adjusting to try to keep the screw connection in the center of the board and to put as much thread into each side of the connection as possible without blowing out. It doesn't absolutely have to be there, that's just going to give you the strongest connection.

Note too that for larger pieces, pocket hole joinery might not be a wise choice. Like anything, it has both strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: So if pocket hole stuff is not supposed to be used, what is the correct alternative?

Comment: What is "correct" depends on what you are actually trying to build.

Comment: That's the key--it doesn't _have_ to be centered. I'd just use the 1-1/2" numbers for everything from there up, or use the numbers for the longest screw length you have on hand.